# Setup Jest Debug with a monorepo Create-React-App with TypeScript and VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I've been hitting my head for about 7 hours now. But this is paramount as I can't afford *not* to develop tests within the app any further (Currently stuck debugging an Apollo React test)

I'm currently under a monorepo with a shared repository and 2 create-react app. I'm using CRACO (Create-React-App Configure Override), and **I can't seem to execute a *debugging* statement using VScode**. I've faced numerous issues: malformed jest commands, transformation problems (css modules not being parsed correctly), hung-up vscode, not found scripts, and many more. I'm stuck and I don't know what else to do.

The monorepo is setup using plain yarn workspaces (no Lerna nor bolt or pmp). It has a shared `component` (with storybook) and 2 create-react apps (app and home respectively). CRACO is used to apply the babel-loader to the shared `component` repo.

I'm able to run the tests with yarn: `cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true CI=true craco test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --maxWorkers=4 --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!date-fns)/\"`, but I haven't been able to either use the traditional debugging or using The Jest Runner vscode extension which is what I want to run specific tests (currently only in the app folder).

Here's my monorepo structure

[image]

These are some of the methods that I've tried:

Here are some of the links that I've visited and tried.

- https://www.basefactor.com/using-visual-studio-code-to-debug-jest-based-unit-tests
- https://github.com/firsttris/vscode-jest-runner
- https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/129
- https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/244
- https://dev.to/shnydercom/monorepos-lerna-typescript-cra-and-storybook-combined-4hli

And many, many more.

I've also tried exporting the jest config using craco and pointing it to the path... nada.

Main (root) package.json

```
{
  "name": "schon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "reactSnap": {
    "inlineCss": true
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.4",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.2.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.55",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/system": "4.9.14",
    "@nivo/calendar": "0.67.0",
    "@nivo/core": "0.67.0",
    "@nivo/line": "0.67.0",
    "@nivo/tooltip": "^0.67.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.3",
    "@snowpack/app-scripts-react": "^2.0.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.13.2",
    "aws-appsync-auth-link": "^2.0.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.714.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "formik-persist": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "immer": "^6.0.9",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.1.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.7",
    "material-table": "^1.59.0",
    "msw": "^0.24.2",
    "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-elastic-carousel": "^0.6.4",
    "react-error-boundary": "^2.2.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.3.0",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.1.1",
    "react-prerendered-component": "^1.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "snowpack": "^3.0.11",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "suneditor": "^2.35.0",
    "suneditor-react": "^2.13.1",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.1",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.4.0",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "validate-password": "^1.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin": "^7.10.4",
    "@craco/craco": "6.1.1",
    "@react-theming/storybook-addon": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.1.19",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.19",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.29.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.13.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.16",
    "@types/linkifyjs": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.154",
    "@types/memoize-one": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.6",
    "@types/randomcolor": "^0.5.5",
    "@types/reach__router": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/react": "17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "@types/tiny-slider-react": "^0.3.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "bolt": "^0.24.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dynamic-cdn-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-json-editor": "^2.5.4",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest-axe": "^3.4.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.0",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.2",
    "microbundle": "^0.12.3",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "react-snap": "^1.23.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.4.2",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.9.0-alpha.24",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.2",
    "typescript": "4.1.2",
    "uglify": "^0.1.5",
    "webpack-cdn-plugin": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "bolt": {
    "workspaces": [
      "./app",
      "./home",
      "./components"
    ]
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "./app",
    "./home",
    "./components"
  ]
}
```

app package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "circular-deps": "ts-node ccd.ts",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start-snowpack-not-working": "snowpack dev --config snowpack.config.js",
    "start": "craco start --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 craco build && yarn run build-snap && yarn run enable-sw",
    "build-snap": "react-snap && npm run generate-sw",
    "enable-sw": "gulp snap-off",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.ts{,x}",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts --ext .tsx src ",
    "test:vscode": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true craco --inspect-brk test",
    "test": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true CI=true craco test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --maxWorkers=4 --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!date-fns)/\"",
    "test:watch": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true CI=true craco test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --maxWorkers=4 --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!date-fns)/\" --watch",
    "test:debug": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true CI=true craco test --inspect-brk test --runInBand --no-cache --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --maxWorkers=4 --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!date-fns)/\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "generate-sw": "sw-precache --root=build --config scripts/sw-precache-config.js && uglifyjs build/service-worker.js -o build/service-worker.js"
  },
  "reactSnap": {
    "inlineCss": true,
    "puppeteerArgs": [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
    ]
  },
  "cracoConfig": "./craco.config.js",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.4",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.2.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.55",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/system": "4.9.14",
    "@nivo/calendar": "0.67.0",
    "@nivo/core": "0.67.0",
    "@nivo/line": "0.67.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.1",
    "aws-appsync-auth-link": "^2.0.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.714.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "components": "*",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "exceljs": "^3.9.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "formik-persist": "^1.1.0",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "immer": "^6.0.9",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.1.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.7",
    "material-table": "^1.59.0",
    "msw": "^0.24.2",
    "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-elastic-carousel": "^0.6.4",
    "react-error-boundary": "^2.2.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.1.1",
    "react-prerendered-component": "^1.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "suneditor-react": "^2.13.1",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "validate-password": "^1.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.1",
    "yup": "^0.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "uglify-js": "3.12.8",
    "@craco/craco": "6.1.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.29.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.5.0",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.13.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.16",
    "@types/linkifyjs": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.154",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.6",
    "@types/randomcolor": "^0.5.5",
    "@types/reach__router": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/react": "17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "@types/tiny-slider-react": "^0.3.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dynamic-cdn-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-json-editor": "^2.5.4",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest-axe": "^3.4.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.0",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.2",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-snap": "^1.23.0",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.1.2",
    "webpack-cdn-plugin": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "apollo-client": "2.6.4"
  }
}
```

The /app/craco.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
/**
 * Allows us to edit create-react-app configuration
 * without ejecting.
 *
 *
 */
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require('@craco/craco');
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../components');
const schonComponents = path.join(
  __dirname,
  './node_modules/@schon/components',
);

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
    

      // https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-create-react-app-in-a-monorepo-a4e6f25be7aa
      const { isFound, match } = getLoader(
        webpackConfig,
        loaderByName('babel-loader'),
      );
      if (isFound) {

        const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include)
          ? match.loader.include
          : [match.loader.include];
        match.loader.include = include.concat(absolutePath, schonComponents);
      }
      return {
        ...webpackConfig,
        optimization: {
          splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
              vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name(module) {
                  // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                  // or node_modules/packageName
                  const packageName = module.context.match(
                    /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/,
                  )[1];
                  // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                  return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };
    },
  },
};
```

And some of the vscode test debugging configs:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    // {
    //   "name": "Debug CRA Tests App",
    //   "type": "node",
    //   "request": "launch",
    //   "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/yarn",
    //   "args": ["workspace app test:debug"],
    //   "env": {
    //     "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK": "true"
    //   },
    //   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    //   "protocol": "inspector",
    //   "console": "integratedTerminal",
    //   "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    // },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "workspace",
        "app",
        "test:vscode",
        "--runInBand",
        "--env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
        "--transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!date-fns)/\""
      ],
      "args": [
        //   "--runInBand",
        //   "--fileDirname", // ADDING THE CURRENT FILENAME DIR FOR THE SCRIPT
        //   "${fileDirname}"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true
      // "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tools/vscode-jest-tests/index.js" // THE SCRIPT
    },
    // {
    //   "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
    //   "type": "node",
    //   "request": "launch",
    //   "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/app/node_modules/.bin/craco",
    //   "runtimeArgs": [
    //     "test",
    //     "--config ${workspaceRoot}\\app\\craco.config.js",
    //     // "--runInBand",
    //     // "--no-cache",
    //     // "--env=jsdom",
    //     "--transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!date-fns)/\"",
    //     "-t"
    //   ],
    //   "env": {
    //     "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK": "true"
    //   },
    //   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/app",
    //   "protocol": "inspector",
    //   "console": "integratedTerminal",
    //   "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    // }
    {
      "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache",
        "--watchAll=false",
        "--config=jest.config.js"
      ],
      "env": {
        "CI": "true",
        "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK": "true"
      },
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/app",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I am stuck too without debugging on Jest with craco on a monorepo with yarn.